# Invalid Type when trying to create Platform Event

Tags: apex, platform-event, type

Ive created a platform event in salesforce and am unable to reference it in my code to trigger the event, below is my event object I have created.

[image]

The error I am receiving can be seen below

> classes/InboundILOS.cls: Invalid type: ILOSRecording_Event__e (Line:
>   22, Column: 9)

And my code where I am trying to create the ILOSRecording_Event__c list is below.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Widgets/*')
global with sharing class InboundILOS {

    @HttpPost 
    global static String createILOS() {
        ILOS_Intergration_Post__c w = new ILOS_Intergration_Post__c();
        String requestBody = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
        w.JSON_Response__c =requestBody;
        JSON2ApexResp resp = JSON2ApexResp.parse(requestBody);
        System.debug(resp.token);
        w.token__c=resp.token;
        w.videoURL__c=resp.videoURL;
        w.embedURL__c=resp.embedURL;
        w.randTag__c=resp.randTag;
        w.iframe__c=resp.iframe;
        List<ILOSRecording_Event__e> e = new List<ILOSRecording_Event__e>();
        insert w;
        return 'Upload Complete';
   }
```

Comment: What API Version are you using? That's pretty vital information here...

Comment: API version is 36.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Platform Event` feature was introduced very recently. Any time you are making use of such a new feature, make sure you **set the API Version to the most up to date value available**.

Comment: And if it's early 2019, and you're editing an old class, you might find this is the reason why sfdx is moaning about unexpected errors.

Comment: I have set the api version to 53.0 but still I'm unable to refer the platform events in contact trigger

Comment: @prasanth Sounds like you should post a question then.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the related *meta.xml file and ensure the  `<apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>` tag is updated properly to anything >= 50